# Change of variables and linear transformations in multiple integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, jacobian

I'm having trouble with a change of variables problem in vector calculus. The question states $D$ is a parallelogram with vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (1,2)$ and $(2,2)$, and $R$ is the rectangle $[0,1] \times [0,2]$. It wants me to determine a linear transformation that maps $D$ in the $x$-$y$ plane to $R$ in the $u$-$v$ plane.

I've plotted the parallelogram $D$ and also plotted the rectangle $R$ but I'm having trouble seeing the necessary change of variables to change the points of $D$ to the points of $R$.

I did notice that most of the points of $D$ already resemble $R$ except for $(2,2)$ in $D$ and $(0,2)$ in $R$ but I'm not sure if I should just eye ball it and guess or if there are formulas for this type of thing, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: One possibility is that you find a formula that converts $(0,0)\mapsto(0,0)$, $(1,0)\mapsto(1,0)$, $(0,2)\mapsto(1,2)$ and $(1,2)\mapsto(2,2)$. Put that formula in a linear transformation $T:D\subseteq\mathbb R^2\to R\subseteq\mathbb R^2\mid T(x,y)=(\qquad,\qquad)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D$ is the region bounded by the lines $y=2x$, $y=2x-2$, $y=0$, $y=2$. Or:

$\frac{2x-y}{2}=0$, $\frac{2x-y}{2}=1$, $y=0$, $y=2$.

So let $u=\frac{2x-y}{2}$ and $v=y$.

---

The answer isn’t unique, notice that the boundary can also be written as: $\frac{y}{2}=0$, $\frac{y}{2}=1$, $2x-y=0$, $2x-y=2$.

So $u=\frac{y}{2}$ and $v=2x-y$ also works.

Comment: brilliant, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! ${}{}{}{}{}$